# Why are Android apk on Google Play market NOT bound to a Google Account?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, apk, ipa

Let's say I published a paid Android app to Google Play for selling.

Let's say user "A" pays for and installs it. Now user 'A' can extract this apk from his device (provided it is rooted) and freely distribute it to other users, who will not have to pay for it anymore.

Hence, as a developer, I lose out. I know the advice to tackle this situation is to request an online login but, for an application that does not require web connectivity for its base functionality, this seems to be a bad practice in terms of usability.

So out of curiosity, why aren't these APKs signed to run for a specific account prior download ? This is what iTunes does with their IPAs, they are signed with the relevant Apple ID.

What are the possible reasons for Android / Google to not follow suite ?

Comment: I think you need to root your phone to extract the apk from your phone.

Comment: Yes that is true, still it is easy enough and once you extract it, the APK can be given to anyone who can use it without paying.

Comment: All the more reason to develop for iOS.:)

Comment: In addition to Quanturium's comment, some file explorers are also possible to "share" the APK without the need of rooting though...